# How do I load multiple yaml files using Snake YAML Java?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a few yaml files in a directory. How do I load all of them into the same YAML Object (Map)?

```
# a.yaml
a: ValueA
c: ValueC

# b.yaml
a: ValueAA
b: ValueB
```

I want to a.yaml, followed by b.yaml. The result would be:

```
{ a: ValueAA, b: ValueB, c: ValueC }
```

One way I could do this is to explicitly concatenate the contents of a.yaml and b.yaml into a single String, and then load the merged String. I would like to know if I can avoid that and just load the 2 yaml files sequentially using the load() API.

Comment: Is that also applicable if the yaml files are separated by tla file separator? (---)  For now I ended up opening multiple input streams and merged them with a SequenceInputStream and SnakeYaml 1.23 is giving the right parsed output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't not include file markers in the example snippet, I think I should have. If I load a single stream of multiple Yaml files, how do I end up with multiple data structures? I'm using a single sequence inputstream as argument to loadAll API, which would return me a single Map of String to Object as response. Atleast that's what I see on my testing. Perhaps that's a snake yaml specific thing?

Comment: Got it. Thanks Anton! I think if you summarize this discussion as an answer, we can close out this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the details of SnakeYAML, but you cannot just concatenate the two files `a.yaml` and `b.yaml`, even if they both have a mapping at the root level.
Doing so you would get a duplicate key in your mapping and according to the YAML 1.2 (and 1.0) specifications you are not allowed to have duplicate keys, and the 1.1 specification states you should get a warning on a duplicate key, and the first value (you indicate you want to have the second).

So you have to resolve this in Java, and you can do so by loading the documents from their respective files and update the data structure loaded from `a.yaml` with the one from `b.yaml`.

You can also concatenate the files into a file with multiple documents, but for that the documents would have to be separated by a directives-end-indicator (`---`) or a document-end-indicator (`...`). You normally need to use a special "load-all" function to load such a multi-document file resulting in a list of (or iterator over) data-structures loaded from the mappings, that you then can merge.

If you make the multi-document file programmatically, make sure to check that the files end in a newline, otherwise appending `---` and the next file is not going to give the multi-document stream you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to Anthon's answer for the details. As a FYI to folks who want to a working snippet, this is what I did.

```
final Yaml yaml = new Yaml(configConstructor, representer);

try (
    final InputStream defaultYamlStream = new FileInputStream(settingsPath + "/cbench-default.yaml");
    final InputStream customerYamlStream = new FileInputStream(settingsPath + "/" + identifier + ".yaml");
    final InputStream fullYamlStream = new SequenceInputStream(defaultYamlStream, customerYamlStream);
) {
    //try
    parsedConfig = (BenchmarkConfig) yaml.load(fullYamlStream);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // ERROR
    System.out.println("Exception parsing the YAML configuration.");
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception parsing the YAML configuration.", ioe);
}
```

I'm creating a stream of concatenated files (sequence stream in my case) and using the load API as recommended by Anthon, and it works fine. Do make a note of the document end markers.

Answer (score 0):

Here a example how to do it with small recursive function (written in Groovy):

```groovy
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.25')
)

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson

def extension = new Yaml().load(("extension.yml" as File).text)
def original = new Yaml().load(("original.yml" as File).text)

println prettyPrint(toJson(original))
println "#############################"

iterateAndOverrite(extension, original)
extension = original

println prettyPrint(toJson(original))

private void iterateAndOverrite(extension, original){
    extension.each {
        if(it.value instanceof Map && original[it.key] != null){
            iterateAndOverrite(extension[it.key], original[it.key])
        } else {
             original[it.key] = extension[it.key]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to override and merge two yaml config, might help someone:

```
 public static void update(Map<String,Object> existingMap,Map<String,Object> newMap){
    newMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if(value instanceof LinkedHashMap){
            LinkedHashMap<String,Object> newMapValue = (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)value;
            LinkedHashMap<String,Object> existingMapValue = (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)existingMap.getOrDefault(key,new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>());
            update(existingMapValue,newMapValue);
        }
        else{
            existingMap.put(key,value);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Reads application.yaml file and loads it to config.
 */
public static void init() throws Exception {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

    //loading config file 1
    InputStream inputStream = ConnectionUtil.class
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("application.yaml");
    config = yaml.load(inputStream);

    //loading config file 2
    String configFile = System.getProperty("config");
    if(configFile!=null){
        File file = new File(configFile);
        if(file.exists()){
            InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(file);
            Map<String,Object> config2 = yaml.load(inputStream2);
            update(config,config2);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid config file path"); 
        
        }
    }

    System.out.println(yaml.dump(config));

}
```